# pre-commit hooks do not find python

Tags: python, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

Using a Windows 10 machine and having pre-commit hooks locally, when I try to create a commit and they are triggered I see that they fail with the error:

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

It is installed, however, and runnable from the command line, so it is unclear to me what is the issue.